# OCLint Xcode 9.3.1 Failure

Tags: xcode9.3, oclint, oclint-json-compilation

I have the following Run Script , available at http://oclint-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/xcode.html

```
source ~/.bash_profile
cd ${SRCROOT}
xcodebuild clean
xcodebuild | xcpretty -r json-compilation-database --output compile_commands.json
oclint-json-compilation-database -- -report-type xcode
```

But, when I execute it, I receive the following error.
(1 failure)
oclint: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!

oclint version is OCLint version 0.13 and Xcode 9.3.1

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: have you tried with last argument as " -report-type html " ?

Comment: It didn't work even after changing 'xcode' to 'html'

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to generate a JSON compilation database from an Xcode project without relying on external tools.
Tested with **Xcode 13.4.1** on macOS 12 Monterey and **Apple Silicon M1 Pro**.

Inside your Xcode Build Settings, or when invoking `xcodebuild` you can set the following compiler flag:
`OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -gen-cdb-fragment-path $(PROJECT_DIR)/CompilationDatabase`

This instructs clang to emit a fragment of the compilation database for each compilation. These fragments can easily be combined into the final compilation database by using the following command:
`sed -e '1s/^/[\'$'\n''/' -e '$s/,$/\'$'\n'']/' *.json > compile_commands.json`

Of course it's a good idea to validate fragments, but that cannot be done without external tools.

For full details regarding compiler flags, validation of fragments, and references, check out the gist:
[Generate a JSON Compilation Database from an Xcode project](https://gist.github.com/T1T4N/f4d63a44476eb5c7046cc561cb8c7f77)